# Clicking on Fragment goes through in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, transparent

I have a button in my `MainActivity` that opens `FragmentA`. `FragmentA` covers the whole screen, but I still see the button from `MainActivity`, and I can still click on it.

I've tried using `clickable` in my fragment layout but it's not working

**MainActivty**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = this@MainActivity.supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, AFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

    <Button
            android:text="Button Main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="true">
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="A"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you placed your `Button` inside of the `ConstraintLayout` you're using as the container of your Fragment.

When you `add` a fragment into a container like what you're doing, it's simply adding it in the same manner as if it was a `View`.

Therefore, if you add a Fragment into a `ConstraintLayout` that already possesses a `Button` as a child, the Fragment will be shown alongside the `Button` due to `ConstraintLayout` allowing for overlapping Views.

*This is also why, if your container was a `LinearLayout`, then adding a Fragment will place the fragment underneath your `Button` instead.*

So, with that in mind, the solution would be to handle it as if they were Views.

If you added a View into a layout and you have another View overlapping, how would you get rid of it?

The most common solution would be to set the Button's visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE when the Fragment is added.

Another solution might be to raise the elevation of the Fragment, so it's now higher than your `Button`.

Of course, you may also remove the button from the Container and place it inside a Fragment too.

This way, you can use the `replace()` method in a `FragmentManager` to replace the Fragment containing your `Button` with the `Fragment` you want to show.

Comment: thanks, i just hide the button whenever the `backstackEntryCount != 0`

Comment: For me, changing layouts or adding elevations didn't work, but checking backstack count to prevent click did the trick. Thanks @Barcode